# populate an array from the @input array in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array coming from @input like this:

```
export interface XXModel {
  id: number;
  category: string;
  serialNumber: string;
  description: string;
}
```

```
@Input() assets: XXModel[];
```

I created another array to get the Id and description  from the previous array to use this array to provide data to a component in the html

```
public _assets:{key:number, value:string}[];
```

How can I fill the _assets array with the id and description from the assets array to populate a component in HTML and receive data from the _assets array?

I tried this approach, but I get undefined and it's not working:

```
@Input() assets: XXModel[];
public _assets:{key:number, value:string}[];
ngOnInit() {
this.assets.map(item => {
if(item){
const {id, description} = item;
this._assets.push({key:id, value:description});
}
});

console.log(this._assets)
}
```

also I tried this way :

```
@Input()
get assets(): XXModel [] {
  return this._assets as any
}
set assets(value: XXModel []) {
  value.map(asset=>{
    this._assets.push({key:asset.id,value:asset.description})
  })
}
public _assets: {key:number, value:string}[];
```

Comment: [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) "return" and array "transformed", so `set assets(value: XXModel []) {this._assets=value.map(x=>({key:x.id,value:x.description}))}`

Answer (score 0):

In angular `@Input` properties don't have a value if accessed inside `ngOnInit` hook. They would have a value first in `ngOnChanges()` hook.

You can just udpdate your code to:

```
class Component implements OnChanges {
    @Input() assets: XXModel[];
    public _assets:{key:number, value:string}[];

    public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        const { assets } = changes;
        if(assets.firstChange) return
        this._assets = this.assets.map(({ id, description }) => ({ key: id, value: description }))
    }
}
```